# JavaScript keeps reloading my page

Tags: javascript

I am running this script on my page to replace `mc=` to `MediaCode=` in my url, the script works but it keeps reloading the page over and over.

This is the script:

```
<script>location.href = location.href.replace('mc=', 'MediaCode=')</script>
```

Comment: Test for mc= before you replace, otherwise location is always replaced and you get redirected..

Comment: So i need to test for it first, and then if its met then proceed onto replacement? Seems logical but i have no idea how to do that :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not put this line into an if condition? This will check whether the URL contains the desired string or not and reload based on that:

```
const mcQueryParam = /mc\=/;

if(location.href.match(mcQueryParam)){
  location.href = location.href.replace(mcQueryParam, "MediaCode=");
}
```

Comment: I don't think that assigning `location.href = location.href` reloads the page - doesn't do it in Chrome console for me at least. Based on Chrome console, I think assigning `location.href = location.href.replace(/mc\=/, 'MediaCode=')` works the same way unless text actually gets replaced and the result is different from `location.href`.

Comment: You’re right… but why does it constantly reload for the OP then?

Comment: I just used this code, it does stop the page looping but it does not replace mc= to Mediacode= in the URL unfortunately :-(

Comment: “Mediacode=”? I thought it was “MediaCode=”. Anyways…maybe it would be helpful if you posted the full URL or at least a bit more of the URL.

Comment: http://landing.premierline.co.uk/our-products2/?mc=GCC16&adgroup=[GCC16%20-%20Brand%20Exact]&matchtype=[Exact]&keyword=[premierline]&channel=googlepaidsearch&gclid=CjwKEAiAveWnBRCzjqf4zpuUkGYSJABcoZbH6XXe6NCKBgj_2WQQzdqfXJvKUY7OXvql5IOlVpLAaRoCfQbw_wcB 

Is the full Url and i need the mc= to change to MediaCode= so it looks like this

http://landing.premierline.co.uk/our-products2/?MediaCode=GCC16&adgroup=[GCC16%20-%20Brand%20Exact]&matchtype=[Exact]&keyword=[premierline]&channel=googlepaidsearch&gclid=CjwKEAiAveWnBRCzjqf4zpuUkGYSJABcoZbH6XXe6NCKBgj_2WQQzdqfXJvKUY7OXvql5IOlVpLAaRoCfQbw_wcB

Comment: But you did try that part with `if(location.href.match(mc=){location.href=location.href.replace(mc=,'MediaCode=');)` as this correct version: `if(location.href.match(/mc\=/)){location.href=location.href.replace(/mc\=/,'MediaCode=');}`, didn’t you? (Those backslashes may not even be necessary—that’s just my constant paranoia of special chars not working…)

Comment: Yes used it both ways but it fails to replace mc=

Answer (score 2):

when you put

```
location.href = someHref
```

you make js to reload the page. Then, I gues, it meets that line again and continues reloading

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is a slight alteration to Xufox's solution

```
    <script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function () {
if(window.location.href.indexOf("mc=") > -1) {
location.href = location.href.replace('mc=', 'MediaCode=')
}});
```

Many thanks to Xufox